# Bayesian analysis of an opinion poll

Tags: bayesian

I'm sorry in advance for rather long questions. This is an example in "Bayesian logical data analysis for physical sciences" by P. C. Gregory and I have some questions about the example.

> In a poll of 800 decided voters, 440 voters supported the political party A. Let's denote the poll result as $D$. The quantity of interest is the probability that the party A will achieve a majority of at least 51% in the upcoming election, assuming the poll will be representative of the population at the time of the election.

The book regards the problem as a model selection problem.

$M_1$ : The party A will achieve a majority with a parameter $H$ that has uniform prior in the range $0.51 \le H \le 1$.

$M_2$ : The party A will not achieve a majority with a parameter $H$ that has uniform prior in the range $0 \le H < 0.51$.

If we have no prior reason to prefer $M_1$ over $M_2$, we can write the odds ratio: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
O_{12}&=p(M_1|D,I)/p(M_2|D,I)\\
&=p(D|M_1,I)/p(D|M_2,I)\\
&=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 p(H|M_1,I)p(D|H,M_1,I) dH }{\int_{0}^{0.51} p(H|M_2,I)p(D|H,M_2,I) dH}\\
&=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 (1/0.49)p(D|H,M_1,I) dH }{\int_{0}^{0.51} (1/0.51)p(D|H,M_2,I) dH}\\
&=87.68
\end{aligned}
$$
Here are my questions:

The book doesn't give explicit expressions for $p(D|H,M_1,I)$ and $p(D|H,M_2,I)$. If I use binomial distribution: 
$$
p(D|H,M_1,I)=p(D|H,M_2,I)=\frac{800! H^{440}(1-H)^{800-440}}{440!(800-440)!}
$$
I get $87.03$ as a result. It is not same to the value $87.68$ of the Book. **What probability distribution should I use for the likelihoods?**

**Why do I have to introduce the models $M_1$ and $M_2$? Why is is this not appropriate to approach the problem like this:** 
$$
O_{12}=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 p(H|D,I) dH}{\int_{0}^{0.51} p(H|D,I) dH}
$$ 
It does not have the factor $(1/0.49)/(1/0.51)$ introduced with the models $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JDL. I have tweaked your question slightly to make it a little more readable. Make sure it's OK with you. If it's not you can click *rollback* to return it to the previous version. I also added the 'homework' tag. I don't know if you're doing this for an official class, or on your own, but HW means that it will be treated differently here. You will get hints to help you work through the ideas, rather than a complete solution. If you don't like that, remove the tag.

Comment: @gung, Thank you for the edit :) The question seems more clear now. But, it is not a homework. It's my own study to understanding basic Bayesian analysis and I removed the homework tag.